# Java - Dynamically Change Kafka Data Type By Input for SpecificAvroSerde

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, avsc

```
import KafkaDataType;
...
...
final Serde<KafkaDataType> eventSchema = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
...
...
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, KafkaDataType> eventStream = builder.stream(STREAM_TOPIC);
```

My `KafkaDataType` is an avro schema that is automatically generated from the associated `.avsc` file. My understanding is that `KafkaDataType` must be pre-defined. However are there existing methods that allow for a dynamic or generic `KafkaDataType`? If so a sample code block would be much appreciated.

The goal is to have the `KafkaDataType` be a generic data type such that different Kafka streams with different avro schemas can be swapped in and out and be processed by the Java code. Currently, for each different avro schema, I would need to change `KafkaDataType` to the specific Java auto generated classes from the `.avsc` schemas.

Let me know if things need more clarification.

Comment: Sounds like you want `GenericAvroSerde` instead

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the guidance! exactly what I needed, and some JSON to get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that KafkaDataType must be pre-defined.

For using a SpecificRecord / serde, yes

> However are there existing methods that allow for a dynamic or generic KafkaDataType?

Avro SpecificRecord classes (such as those generated) extend from `GenericRecord`, which you can use with GenericSerde instead of your specific type to work with multiple types of records in the same stream